# WCSession not responding WatchKit Connectivity Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I am trying to send some data from Apple Watch to iPhone using WCSession. Here is the code for sending the message

```
WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
session.delegate = self;
[session activateSession];

NSDictionary *dict = @{@"time": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.seconds], @"distance": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.distance], @"splits": self.splitsArray, @"max": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", hightest]};

//save data to iphone
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:dict
                           replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
                               //handle reply from iPhone app here
                           }
                           errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"error %@", error);
                           }
 ];
```

This is the code for WCSession delegate in the AppDelegate.

```
#pragma mark - WCsession delegates
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull))replyHandler {

    NSLog(@"recieved message %@", message);

}
```

The log shows that the message was sent from the Apple Watch without any problems, however, `recieved message` was never logged. It seems like the iphone is not responding to the message from the apple watch. What's the problem in this case? thank you!

Comment: Are you activating the WCSession in the iOS app? If so where in the code?

Comment: Oh, I am not. Are you implying that I have to activate WCSession in iOS app as well?

Comment: Yup, your delegate won't receive any delegate callbacks until the session has been activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set the delegate property and activate the WCSession in the iOS app in a part of your iOS app's code that gets run when the iOS app is launched in the background (the UIApplicationDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is a decent place).